# How many offices are there, and how much do they each cost?

Tags: game-dev-story

I am on the 3rd office and about $450,000,000. How much capital do I need to upgrade? Or are there only 3 offices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 3 offices. It costs $600,000 to upgrade to Office 2, and then $2,500,000 to upgrade to Office 3.